# apple push notification is not received through test flight.Although i am using production APNS certificate

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Push Notification is working fine with developer account but not received for production through test flight.
Following are the steps that i have followed-

- I have used Production APNS certificate.and use the following step for p12 file-

  openssl x509 -in prod_identity.cer -inform DER -out prod_identity.pem -outform PEM

  openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in mykey.p12 -out mykey.pem

  openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.pem -in prod_identity.pem -out iphone_prod.p12
- I have used adhoc provisioning profile and also checked for appstore provisioning profile.
- set the build configuration "Release".
  For example-
  edit Scheme->select Archive->set build configuration "Release".
  *In code signing identity-
  select Distribution certificate and for provisioning profile "Adhoc" and also checked for "appstore" provisioning profile.

I have done all the things but still not get the solution for receiving push notification through test flight.I am stuck on this problem from so many days,please help me to find out the solution.

Push Notification are sending successfully from server but not receiving on device.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the url in the server from gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com to gateway.push.apple.com (remove the sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove sanbox (sandbox mode) from push notification url in push sending script.